# Flutter - Debugging

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, debugging

I'm new to flutter and dart. I was recreating an app following a step by step video (I know, many of you will be like "oh no, do your own stuff")...but I'm dealing with errors that the dude in the video doesn't have, and don't know why. Can anybody please explain to me why?
Also, the dependencies don't seem to be updated, but everything I tried to do did not update any of those.

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

[image: image3]

Comment: Issue: the import statement is wrong. you're importing `..models/weather_model.dart`. whereas I can see that in your repo you have folder called `model` and not `models`. So, your import statement should be like below.

import `../model/weather_model.dart`

Friendly reminder: before posting this kind of issues just look at the error closely and try to understand what it's saying.